# Creating a TextView once checkbox is clicked

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

In my activity I would like a TextView to appear below a checkbox once the checkbox has been clicked. How should I do this. Do I need to create a new activity that will display the new TextView below the checkbox. Or can I just use the same activity as before to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in same activity

in the xml create the TextView below CheckBox and `yourTextView.visibility=gone`

in your class write the following code :

```
 yourCheckBox.setonClickListener=new onClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked())
              yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
              yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

}
```

Comment: I am now able to make the TextView appear after the box is checked. But now the problem is that when the box is unchecked again, the TextView still remains visible. I would like the TextViewto be visible only when the box is checked. How do I correct this?? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add the `TextView` to your layout and set `android:visibility="gone"`.

In your `onCheckboxClicked()` set the visibility of the `TextView` to `VISIBLE`

Answer (score 2):

no need to create new activity .Just add textview in your layout file and keep it invisible..when you check the checkbox just make that Textview visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create textbox in onChecked event .

you can refer this :

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    TextView tv;
 CheckBox cbS;
 OnClickListener checkBoxListener;
 checkBoxListener =new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
 //by default keep textview visibility as invisible in xml file;
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE)
 };

 cbS.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. try this..

```
checkBxAutomaticLogin
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        ViewGroup automaticLoginLyt = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
                        LayoutInflater.from(SomeActivity.this).inflate(
                                R.layout.your_layout,
                                automaticLoginLyt, true);
                        editTxtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt_user_name);
                        editTxtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt_password);
                    } else {
                        ViewGroup automaticLoginLyt = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
                        View v = automaticLoginLyt
                                .findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
                        if (v != null) {
                            automaticLoginLyt
                                    .removeView(v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()==true){

                holder.title.setPaintFlags(holder.title.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
            else {

                holder.title.setPaintFlags(holder.title.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you...

```
 holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()==true){

                holder.title.setPaintFlags(holder.title.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
            else {

                holder.title.setPaintFlags(holder.title.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            }
        }
    });
```